# How can I Get Only One Item using Rxjs First() Operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am reading the [Routing and navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#routing-and-navigation) in Angular. The `first()` operator of `rxjs` does not work and I get error.

Here is my Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {
  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    // With the following code I get error
    return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      first(hero => hero.id === +id)
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Hero:

```
export interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Here is my mock-heroes:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

And here is my error:

`Type 'Observable<Hero | Hero[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero>'.
  Type 'Hero | Hero[]' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.
    Type 'Hero[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Hero': id, name`

What I want is to get only the Hero with my intended id; how can I do that?

Comment: In which file it's  throwing the error?

Comment: @SRana, In the HeroService class at return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      first(hero => hero.id === +id)
    );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `of` rather than `from` function to create the Observable returned by `getHeroes()` method.

If you change your code like this you do not get any more the compilation error

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero> {  // the returned Observable emits Hero and not Hero[]
    return from(HEROES);   // from rather thanof
  }

  getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      first(hero => hero.id === +id)
    );
  }
```

With this change, `getHeroes()` emits a stream of `Hero`s and therefore the predicate function you pass to `first` receives just 1 `Hero` at the time and not an array of `Hero`s.

If you want to maintain the original version of `getHeroes()` than you have to change `getHero()` like this

```
getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
  return getHeroes().pipe(
    map(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === +id))
  );
}
```

Comment: OP posted just mock implementation. IRL the service will most probably return `Observable<Heroes[]>`

Comment: @Picci, Could you please explain the mechanism of map and find here? What do they get and what do they return?

Comment: `map` is the rxjs operator that transforms a value received, in this case the array of `Hero`s to something else, in this case one single `Hero`. The transformation is performed by the function passed to `map`. In this case, the function passed to map is `heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === +id)`. The `find` method here is the javascript/typescript method of `Array` and HAS NOTHING TO DO with the rxjs `find` operator that was used in your original code. The `Array.find` method returns the first item which satisfies the condition checked, so it returns just one `Hero`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are returning a `Observable<Hero[]>` and saying this function should return `Observable<Hero>`. I would use `map` instead of `first`.

```
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
......
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    // With the following code I get error
    return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      map(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === +id)),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your stream is `Observable<Hero[]>` so you receive all heroes as an array in the `first` operator.

To convert such stream to `Observable<Hero>` so you receive one hero at a time in the `first` operator, you can use `mergeAll` operator.

```
    return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      first(hero => hero.id === +id)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your array of `Heroes` using `from` instead of `of`.

Like this:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return from(HEROES); // 'from' instead of 'of'.
  }

  getHero(id: string): Observable<Hero> {
    // With the following code I get error
    return this.getHeroes().pipe(
      first(hero => hero.id === +id)
    );
  }
```

`from` streams the values of the array one by one while `of` emits the whole array at once.